# pg_timezone_names view is empty - can be recreated?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

For some strange reason pg_timezone_names view is empty. Is there a way to recreate it?

Comment: select pg_timezone_names(); returns 0 rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pg_timezone_names` view is populated when the server starts - it recursively reads the timezone files from `<your Postgres dir>/share/timezone` and they are used to provide data for the view.

Double check that the files exist (as they should in a full installation) and that the user you are running the database under has read permission on all of the directories and files under `<your Postgres dir>/share/timezone`.

You'll need to restart the RDBMS for changes to take effect.